# Backup all Yum repos and packages on CentOS 5 server?

Tags: centos5, yum

I'm spinning up a new CentOS 5 server and to save some time I'd like to use the same repos and packages as installed on another CentOS 5 server. Is anyone aware of a systematic or best practice method to doing so?

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out DevStructure's [blueprint](http://devstructure.com/). It'll reverse-engineer your server's setup and packages and generate one massive bash script to replay all that on a new server.

Comment: I've installed it and giving it a try. Looks very useful. I'll have some feedback in an hour, thanks!

Comment: I found blueprint to be a breeze and very helpful and portable. Thanks it's a great find!

Answer (score 0):

You could examine the original system's kickstart file generated during installation. That should reside in `/root/anaconda-ks.cfg` and will show some of the basics of the installed system. You could also look at the repo files in `/etc/yum.repos.d` to get an idea of the enabled repos. Finally, you can get an rpm listing from the original server via `rpm -qa | sort -n > rpmlisting.txt` and work from there.

Comment: Interesting I'll examine the kickstart file since blueprint proposed by ceejayoz doesn't seem to go that far. Otherwise blueprint is very systematic. Thanks!